# Hibernate Efficient Use of Session in RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey-2.0

I am currently creating a jersey RESTful web service which exposes data using hibernate and mysql. In creating the service, I have come across several questions regarding proper use of the Hibernate session.

I have created a singleton of the SessionFactory which is used to retrieve new sessions.

```
public class JPAServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JPAServletContextListener.class);

/**
 * Initialize the JPAManager.
 */
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    JPAManager.initializeJPAManager();
    log.info("JPAManager initialized.");

}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    JPAManager.closeJPAManager();
    log.info("JPAManager destroyed successfully.");
}
```

}

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static void initializeJPAManager() {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Currently, anytime an object is needed, the session is opened, the entity is retrieved, and the session is then closed.

```
public static <T> T getEntity(Serializable id, Class<?> klass) {
    Transaction txn = null;
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    T entity = null;
    try {
        txn = session.beginTransaction();
        entity = (T) session.get(klass, id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(String.format("row {} could not be found in the database.", id));
        }
        txn.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        log.debug("Exception encountered while retrieving {} from the database.", id, e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

I am using the Bean Validation API to validate data coming into the service before any information in the database is updated. The bean validations compares the incoming values to the service with the database values to ensure for example that an incorrect currency is not being added to an existing order. Each bean validation is fetching an order entity from the database so if I have 10 bean validations on the POJO, I am looking at 10 separate opening of a session, retrieving the entity, and closing the session via the `getEntity()` method. As the service scales this may be a problem.

Is a better approach to simply open the hibernate session in a Jersey Request Filter, keep it open for the duration of the request, and then close it in a Response Filter? The request specific session could be retrieved via the `getCurrentSession()` as outlined in the [jboss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request). I would be a bit concerned about data integrity as it moves through the service, but the performance gains may warrant this design and it appears to be valid based on the hibernate documentation on session-per-request design patterns.

Comment: Sessions are stateful; REST and HTTP are not.  The two seem orthogonal to me.

Comment: @duffymo true but even REST utilizes the HttpServletRequest which is wiped out at the end of the request. I would liken the Hibernate session to that in that it's only lasting for the duration of the request.

Comment: HTTP servlet request is request scope, not session.  Session means remembering between requests.  Maybe that's what I'm confused about.  The word is overloaded for me.  You mean open a Hibernate session when the request comes in, interact with the database, then close the session and return the response.  Do I have that right?

Comment: @duffymo Your statement is correct. When I say session I am referring to the hibernate session. The hibernate session could be opened at the start of the request, and then closed when the response is sent to the client. This would keep it stateless as no HttpSession would be utilized in this model.

Comment: Now I'm with you.  I agree: a filter or aspect is the right way to go.  I'd prefer an aspect advising a service interface implementation, because that will work whether you deploy via the web or not.  You should have a service interface that owns transactions and units of work.  You happen to choose to deploy it as a REST service now.  Inject that REST service with a reference to your POJO service and let it do the work.